# Store Data to Array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store dynamic data to macro.

1. I have master Excel, that has "numbers"
2. Number in the master Excel dictates how much I loop through to repeat the info (dynamic part)
3. Once I have data in two dimensional array (I know # of columns, but rows could differ - dynamic part) create new file and dump the data, save the file.

Every example I found is MyArray(1 to 5, 1 to 8) --- OK that is good if I knew I had five rows.

I found ReDim - with again known numbers of rows.

What I need is

```
MyArray(n, 1) = Value
MyArray(n, 2) = Value 
.
.
.
MyArray(n+1, 1) = Value
MyArray(n+1, 2) = Value
```

Where n is unknown.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You can use a variable when you `Redim`.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx. You don't need to `ReDim` or size the array - just read the `.Value` of the range in question.

Answer (score 0):

1. My columns and Rows were backward - it's MyArray(col, row) - I had it as MyArray (row, col)
2. I was using ReDim in the wrong place

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
ReDim MyArray(8, 0)

' Enter Data
row = 0
MyArray(0,0) = Value
MyArray(1,0) = Value
...
row = row + 1
ReDim Preserve MyArray(8, row )
```

Comment: So you found out (again) that `ReDim Preserve` acts only upon the last (here: 2nd dimension). - Just a hint to your work around by changed index order: By *transposing* your columns/rows order via `MyArray = Application.Transpose(MyArray)` would allow to regain the commonly used order a) rows, b) columns :-)